# Why can I not access git on a Windows share over VPN?

Tags: windows-server-2008, git

I'm currently connected to a VPN, but the machine I'm on is not connected to the Windows domain that the rest of the network is on.

On that network is a Windows 2008R2 server that I am an admin on. Files on that server can be accessed through Explorer by going `\\server.fqdn\share`.

There is a share on that server called git (can you tell where I'm going yet?). Through Explorer I can go `\\server.fqdn\git\website.git` and see the contents of that folder.

However, I would like to access a git repo in that folder. I know that I can add a remote as `//server.fqdn/git/website.git` but I keep getting an error saying I do not have permission.

I used to get past this error by opening up Windows Explorer, going to `\\server.fqdn\git` and entering my username and password, however this doesn't seem to be working anymore.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than connecting using just my username and password, I used `domain\username` and password (despite being told not to include the domain).

Works fine now.

Comment: What is the git command you used?